# Is there a way to get the vertical padding/margin to be the same as the auto horizontal margin?

Tags: css, padding, margin

I want to set my element to be horizontally centered, and do such with

```css
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Now I want my vertical offset to be the same as my horizontal offset, *except* that it caps it out at a certain point, let's say 100px.

My current solution is using `calc` and `min` and adding it to the padding:

```
div {
    --max-width: 80ch;
    max-width: var(--max-width);
    /* short hand for margin-[left|right] */
    margin-inline: auto;
    /* short hand for padding-[bottom|top] */
    padding-block: min(100px, calc((100% - var(--max-width)) / 2));
}
```

This works, and achieves the result I want. Which again, is that I have the same horizontal and vertical offset, up until a point (100px). At that point the horizontal offset still grows as the page width grows, but the vertical offset is capped at 100px.

but I'm wondering if there's a more simple solution.

[image: centered all around]

[image: only horizontally centered, vertical spacing capped at 100px]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want.

Comment: What would you define as ‘more simple’?

Comment: like a property (or few) that aren't reliant on reusing the width value and doing calculations.

Comment: put your full executable code in a snippet so we can understand more.

Comment: Show to us, some image previews of what you want to understand better your problem

Answer (score 0):

I asume that you want a same effect as

`margin: auto;`

because you want to center the content inside the div.

If this is what you actually trying to achieve, there are several ways to do it. I recomend using flex.

with just 3 lines of code:

```
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
```

Comment: I want to center the element horizontally correct, but I only want to center my element vertically up to a certain point (like 200px). I didn't include it in my original post because I wanted to make it as abstract as possible, but I probably should have, will update. Also flex centers may have loss of data. `safe center` can be used but it's not supported

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full markup and how you are using your CSS, what you have seems to be enough for what you explained you are trying to achieve.

Note however, that your calculation could yield a negative value, but it will not matter since you are using it on the `padding-block` attribute---so the negative padding value will just be ignored. It may be problematic on a `margin-block` attribute. Nevertheless, I'd add a `max(value, 0)` just to ensure it gets `0` as minimum `padding-block` value. Also, you are missing a closing parenthesis before the division operator.

```css
div {
    --width: 100px;
    --max-vertical-offset: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: var(--width);
    margin-inline: auto;
    padding-block: min(var(--max-vertical-offset), max((100vh - var(--width)) / 2, 0px));
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: Should note, I was using `max-width`, not `width`. My variable naming of `--width` might have been a bit confusing Ig. Also you used 100vh so it's measuring off the viewport height, and as such not being equal to the inline margin except in certain cases. I assume you meant 100vw, but my original 100% should work better as it doesn't assume the element's parent is full-width.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div">
  test
</div>
```

Comment: I am aware of those properties yes, but I need vertical padding to be centered only up until a certain point (100px). After that, it caps out and does not increase.